# Obtaining paths to a specific value of a dictionary, expressed as nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I want to write a function that, given as input a nested dictionary like the following:

### Input

```py
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'here', 'd': 'here'}}, 'e': {'f': 'here'}}
```

unpacks the dictionary until it finds the word `"here"`. When it does, I want it to save a nested dictionary that represents the path followed to reach that point. I want as output a list of all the paths that lead to the word `"here"` So, in this example the expected output is a list of three dictionaries:

### Expected output

```py
[
{'a': {'b': 'c'}},
{'a': {'b': 'd'}}
{'e': 'f'}
]
```

Note that the dictionary could have an arbitrary number of nested levels, this was just a simple example.

### My best attempt

Currently, I was only able to implement a version of this which outputs a list instead of a nested dictionary.

```py
def find_word(dictionary, path=[]):
    results = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        new_path = path + [key]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            results.extend(find_word(value, new_path))
        elif value == 'here':
            results.append(new_path)
    return results
# Example usage
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'here', 'd': 'here'}}, 'e': {'f': 'here'}}
paths = find_word(d)
for path in paths:
    print(path)
```

##### Output

```py
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'd']
['e', 'f']
```

but for my application I would need a list of nested dicts rather than a list of lists.

Comment: You rarely ever really need a set of nested dictionaries. What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you just want to map an arbitrary number of inputs to a value then you should work with tuples instead (e.g: use ('a', 'b', 'c') as key instead of having three nested dictionaries). Make sure that you are not falling in this pitfall https://xyproblem.info :)

Comment: In your expected output, you do not have the values of the last level. Do you just need the keys and no values?

Comment: @GodIsOne Yes, I would just need the path to the word `'here'`, but not the value itself

Comment: @MarcelFerrari I see your point ;) but I'm quite sure I need it in that form. The reason is that this is a MRE for a complicated project in which I want to reuse a function that takes as input nested dictionaries. So, I could avoid using nested dictionaries, but then I would need to re-write that function to take lists as input, and that is more time consuming that trying to solve this

Comment: check this library it will help you immensely: https://github.com/dpath-maintainers/dpath-python

Comment: @GodIsOne That looks great! You think it would be applicable also for sloving this problem?

Comment: yes, I guess, it is pretty versatile, you need to take some time and have a look.

Comment: I think this will help: https://gist.github.com/SegFaultAX/b926fe97c2ac1db1fb313f3a9372ee56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```py
def find_paths(data, target_value, current_path=None):
    if current_path is None:
        current_path = []

    paths = []

    for key, value in data.items():
        new_path = current_path + [key]

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            paths += find_paths(value, target_value, new_path)
        elif value == target_value:
            # create nested dictionary from the list of keys
            path_dict = {}
            temp = path_dict
            for k in new_path[:-2]:
                temp[k] = {}
                temp = temp[k]
            temp[new_path[-2]] = new_path[-1]
            paths.append(path_dict)

    return paths
```

Only test I ran is this, but it seems like I didn't mess anything up

```py
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'here', 'd': 'here'}}, 'e': {'f': 'here'}}
print(find_paths(d, 'here'))
```

```
marcelferrari$ python test.py 
[{'a': {'b': 'c'}}, {'a': {'b': 'd'}}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert your list of lists to a list of nested dicts using recursion.

```
def list_to_nested(l):
    d = {}
    if len(l) != 1:
        d[l[0]] = list_to_nested(l[1:])
    else:
        return l[0]
    return d
```

**Result:**

`print(list_to_nested(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']))`

> `{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {'e': {'f': 'g'}}}}}}`

Comment: You are right, I could just do this, but I'm looking for a more compact version where I create the dictionary in the function itself. If there is no other way, I will go for your solution